# Absolute positioned elements on high dpi display out of alignment

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project for one of my classes and have ran into an odd positioning issue. I have two gear icons from the font-awesome library displayed with a text logo. One gear is sized larger and positioned slightly offscreen while the other is positioned almost touching the larger gear. On my laptop in chrome the elements displays correctly at the default 16px font size. When I switch to my desktop (with a 50 inch 4k tv display with chrome set to increase font sizes at 20px) the gears are out of alignment.

My question: how can I position the two icons so that they are consistent regardless of user-defined text size?

Relevant CSS:

```
div.logo i.cog-logo-small {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 20px;
    left: 32px;
}

div.logo i.cog-logo, div.logo i.cog-logo-small {
    position: absolute;
}

div.logo i, div.logo a {
    color: #c06014;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

div.logo i.cog-logo {
    font-size: 3em;
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
}
```

Relevant HTML

```
<nav class="top-bar clearfix">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
            <i class="cog-logo fa fa-cog gear-spin fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="cog-logo-small fa fa-cog gear-spin-reverse fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="logotext">logotext</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tagline">tagline</span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is your code... does it reproduce your current layout? They aren't moving around for me at different screen sizes. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmJdOL

Comment: the issue isnt screen size but rather when the user sets a custom font size within chrome. My current desktop has to use a larger font size due to the physical size of my screen while my desktop uses a standard font size in the chrome settings. even the code-pen example you linked has the same effect when you change chrome's font size (you can reproduce by going to chrome://settings > advanced settings > web content > font size)

Comment: You should try to not combine `em` which is a relative size with `px` that is very specific.

Comment: How about this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/RVOeXb or https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/oWOarV

Comment: in that case would it be acceptable to adjust the positioning using em or do you suggest converting everything to px?

Comment: Excellent! the EM revision with translate is excatly what I was looking for. This has been driving me nuts for a few hours now :) Thank you for the assistance @mich

Comment: sweet, you bet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the fixed unit (`px`) positioning. Fixed units often do not scale as expected when zooming in the browser. A better approach is to use relative units (`em`, `%`, etc) that will change relatively as the zoom level changes.

Here's a solution using `em` for your `top/left`

```css
div.logo i.cog-logo-small {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 1em;
    left: 1em;
}

div.logo i.cog-logo, div.logo i.cog-logo-small {
    position: absolute;
}

div.logo i, div.logo a {
    color: #c06014;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

div.logo i.cog-logo {
    font-size: 3em;
    top: -.25em;
    left: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="top-bar clearfix">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="cog-logo fa fa-cog gear-spin fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="cog-logo-small fa fa-cog gear-spin-reverse fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="logotext">logotext</span>
    </a>
    <span class="tagline">tagline</span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or here is another using `%` in combination with `transform: translate()`

```css
div.logo i.cog-logo-small {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transform: translate(20%,20%);
}

div.logo i.cog-logo,
div.logo i.cog-logo-small {
  position: absolute;
}

div.logo i,
div.logo a {
  color: #c06014;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

div.logo i.cog-logo {
  font-size: 3em;
  transform: translate(-85%,-65%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="top-bar clearfix">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="cog-logo fa fa-cog gear-spin fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="cog-logo-small fa fa-cog gear-spin-reverse fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="logotext">logotext</span>
    </a>
    <span class="tagline">tagline</span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Coker figured out the issue was in combining px and em measurements. Switching to a translate will solve the issue and allow the text icon to scale when switching font sizes in the browser.

```
div.logo i.cog-logo-small {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transform: translate(20%,20%);
}
```

If this does not work you might also try converting all measurements to em and it will create a similar effect.